# Is there a way to simplify that source code?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm currently implementing a bulletin board API using a spring boot.
The scenario for the source code I'm going to show you is about the bulletin board or comment modifications,

Both are required to submit the password at the time of comment or bulletin board input before modification.

So, I simply use the **'isBoard'** for input:hidden value to perform the **'findById'** in the **'boardRepository'** and compare it with the matching functions of the passwordEncoder and then update the Boolean value.

However, the code below shows that the same logic is duplicated and used.
Is there a way to make this simpler?

```
 @Transactional
public boolean tryToUpdateArticleOrReply(Long id, String password, boolean isBoard) throws ApiException {
    AtomicBoolean result = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    if(isBoard) {
         boardRepository.findById(id).ifPresent(
                board -> {
                    result.compareAndSet(passwordEncoder.matches(board.getUserPass(), password), true);
                }
         );
    } else {
        replyRepository.findById(id).ifPresent(
                reply -> {
                    result.compareAndSet(passwordEncoder.matches(reply.getUserPass(), password), true);
                }
        );
    }
    if(result.get())
      return result.get();

    throw new ApiException("INVALID_USER_PASS", "you submitted invaild password.", new ApiExceptionData().add("user_pass", password));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `findById` and `getUserPass` methods come from interfaces (and the `findById` method returns the interface that `getUserPass` comes from), then you can simply do:

```
private boolean check(FindByIdInterface repository,
                      Long id,
                      String password) {
    return repository.findById(id)
            .map(result -> 
                passwordEncoder.matches(
                    result.getUserPass(), password))
            .orElse(false); 
}
```

And then just call it where you select which `repository` to pass based on your `isBoard` variable.  `isBoard ? boardRepository : replyRepository`

---

If they *don't* come from shared interface(s), then you can effectively 'pretend' they do using some of the functional interfaces from java.

```
/* R = repository type, T = return type of 'findById' */
private <R, T> check(Function<R, Optional<T>> getByIdMapper,
                     Function<T, String> getUserPassMapper,
                     R repository,
                     Long id,
                     String password) {
    return getByIdMapper.apply(repository)
            .map(result ->
                passwordEncoder.matches(
                    getUserPassMapper.apply(result),
                    password))
            .orElse(false);
}
```

And then call it with something like:

```
if (isBoard) {
    return check(BoardRepository::getById,
                 Board::getUserPass,
                 boardRepository, id, password);
} else {
    // ...
}
```

---

Note, in neither case was an `AtomicBoolean` necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
@Transactional
public boolean tryToUpdateArticleOrReply(Long id, String password, boolean isBoard) throws ApiException {
    Optional<String> optUserPass;
    if (isBoard) {
        optUserPass = boardRepository.findById(id).map(Board::getUserPass);
    else {
        optUserPass = replyRepository.findById(id).map(Reply::getUserPass);
    }
    if (optUserPass.isPresent() && passwordEncoder.matches(password, optUserPass.get()))
        return true;
    throw new ApiException("INVALID_USER_PASS", "you submitted invaild password.", new ApiExceptionData().add("user_pass", password));
}
```

*Note 1:* The method name seems a bit off.

*Note 2:* Why have `boolean` return type when it can only ever return `true`?